# Is there a way to import tables from Snowflake to data frames in R without installing any driver?

Tags: r, import, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a way to automate the importing of a table from Snowflake to a data frame in R. **Better if I can put that task into an Rscript**. Currently, I still have to manually gather the table and save it in my local as CSV file and use the `read.csv()` function in my R in order to import that table coming from Snowflake. This is very tedious and counterproductive which is why it would be best to automate it.

Here's another thing. I don't have admin privileges on my laptop which is very unfortunate for me because **I cannot install the Snowflake driver** to connect to the database. Also tried to reach out to our IT support for almost a month now but to no avail, so if you know a way to import tables from Snowflake to R without the need to install any software, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: Since you mention "admin" and it's a laptop, is this Windows? If so, Windows installers require admin, but you can usually copy files without needing admin permissions. If you can, several of the drivers on Windows do not require the running of an installer. For example, the JDBC driver is just a JAR file and does not require installation. If you have Python, you can probably use pip to install the Python driver without admin. Either of these can get you automated access to the tables. The Spark connector probably does not require an installer to run either, just a file pull from Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denelle! Look what I've just found about your problem:

1. `dplyr` and stuff:
   https://www.snowflake.com/blog/integrating-the-snowflake-data-warehouse-with-r-via-dplyr/
2. Here's the driver installation is required:
   https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Connect-Snowflake-with-R-RStudio-using-RODBC-driver-on-Windows-MacOS-Linux
3. RStudio community forum with the same problem as yours:
   https://community.rstudio.com/t/connecting-rstudio-connect-with-snowflake/63796/12

I am not really familiar with Snowflake warehouse, but I guess that there is no way to connect without launching driver, which you cannot install.

Comment: That's correct. I really had no other choice but to do several follow-ups on our IT support. I already have the driver installed on my laptop. Thanks for your response.